# Replicate a range of values if condition is satisfied

Tags: r, rep

I am attempting to add a column (Transaction) to the below sample data frame in which the logic is that for every "New Value" in the index column, the replication of the values will start over. The value in index will be labeled "New" at random amongst the entire data frame (150,000+ rows). I'm looking to have the first row start with 1 and after every 1:3 sequence, the sequence will start over at 1 after 3 unless there is "New" in the index column, in which the sequence automatically starts back over at 1. I have attempted utilizing `rep()` and `ifelse` in various combinations with little success. Also, the Transaction column is currently empty with no values. Thank you in advance!

| Index | Transaction |
| --- | --- |
|  | 1 |
|  | 2 |
|  | 3 |
|  | 1 |
|  | 2 |
|  | 3 |
| New | 1 |
|  | 2 |
| New | 1 |
|  | 2 |
|  | 3 |
|  | 1 |
| New | 1 |
|  | 2 |

Comment: Can you fill out the index column more? It would be good to see what exactly is in there.

Comment: This is an accurate depiction of the index column. The purpose of the column in this case is to identify when an attribute changes from one value to the next. For example, the first 6 rows could be related to 101, but the 7th row is 102 and labeled as "New" or rather there are no other values except "New" or blank.

Comment: see my attempt below.

Comment: Thank you! This appears to be working as requested. I need to spend some time understanding exactly what is happening, especially with cumsum. I didn't even consider group_by  and then ungroup.

Comment: `cumsum` is creating an index we can use to group by. First you create a binary vector and then you sum the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a first attempt:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Creating the data frame: 
df <- data.frame(index = rep("", 14))
df[c(7,9,13), 'index'] <- 'New'


# Defining a run index:
df$run <- cumsum(df$index == "New")


df %>% 
  group_by(run) %>% 
  mutate(Transaction = ifelse( (1:n())%%3==0, 3, 1:n()%%3  )) %>%
  ungroup() %>% select(-run)

  # A tibble: 14 x 2
   index Transaction
   <chr>       <dbl>
 1 ""              1
 2 ""              2
 3 ""              3
 4 ""              1
 5 ""              2
 6 ""              3
 7 "New"           1
 8 ""              2
 9 "New"           1
10 ""              2
11 ""              3
12 ""              1
13 "New"           1
14 ""              2
```